# Is Hibernate native api with JTA and Without EJB possible?

Tags: hibernate

I try to migrate an existing project into Wilfly. The problem comes with hibernate and JTA. The project uses Hibernate 4.3 with native api(So no JPA, and no EJB).
So i have configured hibernate.cfg.xml like this :

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">jta</property>
  <property name="jta.UserTransaction">java:/TransactionManager</property>
  <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform</property>
```

With this, i get

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: No TransactionManagerLookup
>   specified

Does the use of Hibernate native api is possible, and how to specify a TransactionManagerLookup?

This is how the session is retrived in the old way

```
  public class HibernateSessionFactory {


    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(HibernateSessionFactory.class);
    private static final String PATH_CONF_FILE = "/hibernate.cfg.xml";
    private static final ThreadLocal<Session> THREAD_LOCAL = new ThreadLocal<Session>();
    private static final ThreadLocal<Session> SESSION_JDBC = new ThreadLocal<Session>();
    private static final ThreadLocal<StatelessSession> THREAD_LOCAL_STATELESS = new ThreadLocal<StatelessSession>();
    private static Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    private static String configFile = PATH_CONF_FILE;
    private static String nameDataSource;
    private static javax.naming.Context ictx;
    public static final String URL = "http-remoting://localhost:8080";
    public static final String FACTORY = "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory";
    private static final String USER_TRANSACTION = "javax.transaction.UserTransaction";
    public static final String DATASOURCE_GLOBE = "App";
    public static final String DATASOURCE_APP = "AppQuartz";
    private static boolean isBuilding = false;
    public static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private HibernateSessionFactory() {
        recuperationContext();
    }

    public static String getNameDataSource() {
        return nameDataSource;
    }

    public static void setNameDataSource(final String pNameDataSource) {
        nameDataSource = pNameDataSource;
    }

    private static void recuperationContext() {
        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, URL);
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, FACTORY);
        try {
            ictx = new InitialContext(env);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Echec dans la récupération du context jndi ", e);
        }
    }

    public static javax.naming.Context getIctx() {
        if (ictx == null) {
            recuperationContext();
        }
        return ictx;
    }

    public static Session getSession() {
        if (session == null || !session.isOpen()) {
            if (sessionFactory == null) {
                rebuildSessionFactory();
            }
            session = (sessionFactory != null) ? sessionFactory.openSession() : null;
            THREAD_LOCAL.set(session);
        }
        return session;
    }

    public static StatelessSession getStatelessSession() {
        StatelessSession session = THREAD_LOCAL_STATELESS.get();
        if (session == null) {
            if (sessionFactory == null) {
                rebuildSessionFactory();
            }
            session = (sessionFactory != null) ? sessionFactory.openStatelessSession() : null;
            THREAD_LOCAL_STATELESS.set(session);
        }
        return session;
    }

    public static void beginTransaction() {
        Session session = getSession();
        if (!session.getTransaction().isActive()) {
            session.beginTransaction();
        }
    }

    public static void commit() {
        Session session = getSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        if (session.getTransaction().isActive()) {
            tx = session.getTransaction();
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.commit();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void rollback() {
        Session session = getSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        if (session.getTransaction().isActive()) {
            tx = session.getTransaction();
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
                session.clear();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void rebuildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            if (!isBuilding) {
                isBuilding = true;
                configuration = new Configuration();
                configuration.configure(configFile);
                StandardServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
                serviceRegistryBuilder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
                ServiceRegistry svcReg = serviceRegistryBuilder.build();
                sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(svcReg);
                isBuilding = false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            isBuilding = false;
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static void closeSession() {
        Session session = THREAD_LOCAL.get();
        THREAD_LOCAL.set(null);

        if (session != null && session.isOpen()) {
            session.close();
        }
    }

    public static org.hibernate.SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void setConfigFile(final String pConfigFile) {
        HibernateSessionFactory.configFile = pConfigFile;
        sessionFactory = null;
    }

    public static Configuration getConfiguration() {
        return configuration;
    }

    public static String getConfigFile() {
        return configFile;
    }
}
```

But this way, i explode pool connection on wildfly.
In the new way, i use this hibernateSessionFactory :

```
public class HibernateSessionFactory {


    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(HibernateSessionFactory.class);
    private static final String PATH_CONF_FILE = "/hibernate.cfg.xml";
    private static String configFile = PATH_CONF_FILE;
    public static final String DATASOURCE_APP = "App";
    public static final String DATASOURCE_QUARTZ = "AppQuartz";
    public static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure(configFile);
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
            serviceRegistryBuilder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
            ServiceRegistry svcReg = serviceRegistryBuilder.build();
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(svcReg);
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            LOG.fatal("Failed to create session factory." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    public static void beginTransaction() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        if (!session.getTransaction().isActive()) {
            session.beginTransaction();
        }
    }

    public static void closeSession() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        if (session != null && session.isOpen()) {
            session.close();
        }
    }

    public static void commit() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        if (session.getTransaction().isActive()) {
            tx = session.getTransaction();
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.commit();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void rollback() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        if (session.getTransaction().isActive()) {
            tx = session.getTransaction();
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
                session.clear();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the stacktrace of the error :

```
5:47:11,434 ERROR [dao.OrganismeDAO] (MSC service thread 1-16) recuperation echoué: org.hibernate.HibernateException: createQuery is not valid without active transaction
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:352) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy59.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at dao.OrganismeDAO.getSomething(Something.java:519) [classes:]
    at util.Constantes.setCODESOMETHING(Constantes.java:273) [classes:]
    at struts.plugin.startup.initialisation.Initialisation.execute(Initialisation.java:42) [classes:]
    at struts.plugin.StartupManager.init(StartupManager.java:92) [classes:]
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModulePlugIns(ActionServlet.java:871) [struts-core-1.3.10.jar:1.3.10]
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:359) [struts-core-1.3.10.jar:1.3.10]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:79)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:220) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:125) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:509) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:88)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.start(UndertowDeploymentService.java:72)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
```

And the code that make this stacktrace :

```
 public String getSomething() {

        try {
            StringBuffer queryString = new StringBuffer();
            queryString.append("select b.foo ");
            queryString.append("from bar b ");

            return (String) getSession().createQuery(queryString.toString()).uniqueResult();
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            throw re;
        }
    }
```

And the datasource :

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/App" pool-name="App" enabled="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/app</connection-url>
                    <driver>postgresql</driver>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>2</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
                        <prefill>true</prefill>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>****</user-name>
                        <password>****</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                        <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLExceptionSorter"/>
                    </validation>
                    <timeout>
                        <idle-timeout-minutes>20</idle-timeout-minutes>
                    </timeout>
                    <statement>
                        <track-statements>true</track-statements>
                    </statement>
                </datasource>
```

Comment: 1. Please can you show how your Hibernate session factory is configured? 2. Also please show what that SESSION_JDBC is?

Comment: Please can you show the stack trace you are getting saying createQuery needs a transaction, and the snippet of code that is getting the Hibernate session and creating the query. Also please show your datasource definition.

Comment: What happens if you update your calling code so that you call beginTransaction() on your Hibernate session before executing the query, and then commit() after the query runs?

Comment: It works. But i have thousands request to modify

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have an app written using Jonas and EJBs, and you want to move it to Wildfly? You work boils down to three things:

1. Figure out if you really need JTA / extended transactions. If you need JTA, choose a JTA transaction manager.
2. Figure out where the transaction boundaries were in the old application. This is essential if you are to maintain the same transactional behaviour when you port the app. e.g. for many apps with a service layer and a dao layer, the transaction boundaries are at the business service level, because that represents the unit of work, which may include multiple interactions with the database
3. Decide how you are going to start the transactions. If the old app used EJBs with container managed transactions, they would be started "for free", so as you have stated that you don't want to use EJBs, you will need to figure out another mechanism for starting the transactions.

Here are some pointers for these three tasks.

Task 1 - JTA Transactions

Many applications only need local transactions, as you only need JTA transactions if you need to synchronize across multiple resources. e.g. you have an operation that stores data in a database and also posts a message to a message queue, and you need to rollback the entire operation if one part fails.

If you are certain that you really need JTA transactions, the next thing is to decide which JTA Transaction Manager you want to use. Here are some choices:

Narayana
http://narayana.io/

This is actually bundled with Wildfly. Hence in theory it should be the easiest to integrate with.

However if you prefer not to use Narayana, there are others. e.g.

Atomikos
http://www.atomikos.com

Bitronix
https://github.com/bitronix/btm

Task 2 - Figure out where the transaction boundaries were in the old app

This is one for you. If your old app was using EJB with container managed transactions on Jonas, you need to look at the configuration it used to define which bits of code needed transactions. e.g. was it at the service layer? or the dao layer?

Task 3 - Figure out how to start the transactions

As your question suggests the app was making use of EJB container managed transactions, meaning the code did not have to specify the transaction boundaries. One problem you will face if you want to run this code outside of a container is you will need to specify the transaction boundaries, there is no way round that. Without knowing the structure of your code it is difficult to give precise pointers on how to do that with the minimum of changes but ideally you want a way that doesn't involve changing too many classes. The most popular choice is probably to use an annotation approach. e.g.

[Wildfly 8.0.0.Final JTA transaction issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22163826/wildfly-8-0-0-final-jta-transaction-issues)

Comment: No i can't, it's an old project, that use Strut 1.x. But i must migrate it to wildfly. If i use thread instead jta, i need to rewrite all of hibernate queries because they don't use explicit transactions.

Comment: How are your transactions being started and committed? Are you using native Hibernate transactions, or something else?

Comment: Currently the requests are of the form : (String) getSession().createQuery(queryString.toString()).uniqueResult(); So i suppose transactions are managed automatically. The old server was a Jonas 5 Server

Comment: Why do you want JTA transactions? They are only required if you need to synchronize across multiple resources (databases / message queues). Is that a requirement in your app?

Comment: if by message queues you mean JMS , yes it's a requirement. And i go to JTA to not have to open and close transaction for all of the thousands queries in the application

Comment: You don't need JTA to avoid opening and closing transactions. You can have code that doesn't make any use of transactions if your app is simple and each operation is a single change, or you don't need atomic commits to group changes. Secondly, you can use as many databases and message queues as you want without JTA. You only need JTA specifically if you have one or more pieces of code that need to write to multiple resources in a single atomic commit. Do you definitely need that? How does the app specify the transaction boundaries, can you give an example of the config / code?

Comment: The application is really complexe and needs to use transactions. There is lot of complexe business code. Can i skip JTA and have the transactions managed automatically? If i switch to thread, i have the following error : createQuery is not valid without active transaction

Comment: if i replace sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() by the old way, sessionFactory.openSession() the error go off, but i literally explodes the server pool connection